# How to get nsstring matching count with other nsstring object?

Tags: cocoa, string-matching

I searching a way to get match count of nsstring objects for a long time.
but I can't find.
How to get match count of String_one and String_Two?
I need your help..

```
NSString *String_one = @"A!B!C!D!E!F!G";
NSString *String_Two = @"BEF";

// matching progress
// :
// :

// and then result display
NSLog(@"matching count : %d",[??????]);

// result what i want.
// matching count : 3      (A!B!C!D!E!F!G vs BEF => 3 character matches)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, tell me what must be return in this example:  ABCDEF vs ACB.  I don't know that you want only count how many character from first string appear in second string, or it must be subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find longest common subsequence here you have link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

But if you want count only how many how many character from first string appear in second string you can write algorithm by yourself. Example:

```
for ( each character in StringFirst ) {
    if( character appear in StringSecond ) 
         ++count;
}
```